# JQuery mobile google adsense error in higher Android version

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, adsense

I am working with Jquery Mobile (jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js) for an APP. I have successfully integrated google adsense to my app pages. But I have few Questions and issues.

1. [Is it legally possible to monetize a mobile app with jQuery Mobile and Google Adsense?](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-phonegap-google-adsense) After google Aquired Admob.
2. I am running Google Website Add to my Mobile App as I am not able to get a Mobile app ads from google. Is it violating Google Adsense Policy?
3. My Ads Work and display well in Android Lower end Mobile. Ads display in Android 2.4 Version Mobile but not in Android 4.4 Versions. Do i want to do any additional work?

My Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX";
        /* My Project */
        google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
        google_ad_width = 320;
        google_ad_height = 50;
        //-->
    </script>


   <div data-role='footer' data-theme='a' data-position='fixed' role='contentinfo' class='ui-footer ui-bar-b ui-footer-fixed slideup'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js'>
        </script>
    </div>
```

Kindly let e know what I can do to make it work! Thanks in Advance.